# XBAP refresh event

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation, xbap

I am developing an xbap application and have run into a problem with users refreshing the application using F5, which results in an immediate application crash. The workaround is to use the browsers refresh button. This reloads the application as expected.

What exactly happens when the user presses F5 in an xbap? Is there any way to override this behavior, or at least make it work as if the user pressed the button in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a simple override to ignore the refresh, and tell the users to use the browsers button instead.

```
    Application.Current.Navigating += new NavigatingCancelEventHandler(Current_Navigating);  
    ..
    void Current_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Refresh)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```